# x axis rotation in boxplot using xticklabel_rotate [MATLAB 2012]

Tags: matlab

I have a question about the boxplot function in matlab. Actually I want to plot a matrix `M <49x85 double>` (85 point, 49 simulation). The x axis is `namesNode<1x85 cell>` each cell contain a string (name). The problem is that the x axis is illegible while using `boxplot` because it has too much data.

ScreenCap : [image: boxplot]

So my idea is to use xticklabel_rotate because I am using MATLAB 2012 ('LabelOrientation' is not allowed in M2012) [xticklabel_rotate](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate)

but then while using it I receive

> xticklabel_rotate : can not process, either xticklabel_rotate has already been run or XTickLabel field has been erased

Any suggestions how can I plot the x axis correctly?

Here is the code :

```
function [ ] = CompChuteTension( X,Y )

A=[];
B=[];
C=[];

j=0;
c=(length(X)-1)/49;
while j<=48 
    for i=1:c
       A(i,j+1)= abs(amp(cell2mat(X(i+1+j*c,5)),cell2mat(X(i+1+j*c,9)))...
                     -amp(cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,5)),cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,9))))/amp(cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,5)),cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,9)));

        B(i,j+1)= abs(amp(cell2mat(X(i+1+j*c,6)),cell2mat(X(i+1+j*c,10)))...
                     -amp(cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,6)),cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,10))))/amp(cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,6)),cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,10)));

        C(i,j+1)= abs(amp(cell2mat(X(i+1+j*c,7)),cell2mat(X(i+1+j*c,11)))...
                     -amp(cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,7)),cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,11))))/amp(cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,7)),cell2mat(Y(i+1+j*c,11)));

    end
    j=j+1;
end
H=[];
M=transpose(A*100);
N=transpose(B*100);
P=transpose(C*100);
Z={};
for i=1:size(M,2)
Z=[Z strcat(num2str(i),'A') strcat(num2str(i),'B') strcat(num2str(i),'C')];
end

for i=1:size(M,2)
H=[H M(:,i) N(:,i) P(:,i)];
end

array = {} ;
[num01,txt01,tab01]=xlsread('result_11.xlsx',1);
S = {} ;
for i=1:85
    S(1,i) = txt01(i,3) ;
    array = [ array S{i} ] ;
end 

boxplot(M,array);
xticklabel_rotate([],90,[]);

   end
```

I shared the two excel files :

[result_11](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmAxMzTOfN4YhBbFZyXBaXK5rZyv)
[result_12](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmAxMzTOfN4YhBh4Zl7EYrbTZJFq)

The main :

```
function[]=results()
[num1,txt1,tab1]=xlsread('result_11.xlsx',1);
[num2,txt2,tab2]=xlsread('result_12.xlsx',1);
CompChuteTension(tab1,tab2);
end
```

also :

```
function[x]=amp(a,b)
x=sqrt(a*a+b*b)
end
```

Comment: Shows us the code. [mcve]

Comment: You don't provide a minimal example, so it's hard to answer your question. But you probably run the xticklabel_rotate function several time on the same figure which is not supported.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I just uploaded the code.

Comment: @obchardon Sir I don't think so, even the first time it hasn't worked

Comment: @ladssjss I provided a link, please read it. Your example is not **Complete**, as I can not run it without example data. You example is not **Minimal** because it has code that is unnecessary for the problem you have. Therefore your example is neither **Verifiable**.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I am sorry for this, I am new here. I think my example is complete now.

Comment: The problem concerns the `xticklabel_rotate`,.. but your code don't call this function !

Comment: Hi @obchardon, yes you are right, but in any case you can use `xticklabel_rotate` just after `boxplot(M,array);` (I edited my post)

Comment: have you try to add the function "figure" just before the function "boxplot" ?

Comment: Yes I did, and I do have a figure, but the problem is that I have much data on the x axis, anyway I guess I will just try to download a new MATLAB version.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right for SO to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted.